# Rebuilding a RAID 1 without data loss, recover from unallocated partition data

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning, raid, data-recovery

**Mobo**: ASUS P8Z77-M/Pro Gen 3
**RAM**: 32GB (4 x 8GB)
**Power Supply**: corsair HX850
**HDDs**:Configuration before the problem:
1 x 128GB SSD for Windows 7 professional 64-bit
2 x 3TB drives in RAID 1 on the intel Z77 controller.
2 partitions on these disks: My Documents (0.2TB); Pictures (2.8TB)
these partitions are shown in windows like 2 disks (disk1 and Disk2).  Respectively G and H letters. Layout:
*Disk 1 : G: My Documents (0.2TB)*
*Disk 2: H: Pictures (2.7TB)*

**Graphics**:
NVidia Quadro 600 (not using on-board graphics)  •  Os: Windows 7 64 professional

**The problem**
Yesterday, Windows crashed. I had to restart computer with repaired disk.
Now my 2 x 3TB are not in RAID 1.
Windows shows 2 disks with 2 partitions each, first named “My Documents” and the second “unallocated”.
Layout:
Disk 1: G:My Documents (0.2TB) | unallocated (2.7TB)
Disk 2: H:My Documents (0.2TB) | unallocated (2.7TB)
Accordingly: I no longer have access to my photographs.

**What I’ve checked**
Intel RST works well, and it shows that disks are not in RAID

**Could you help me?**
My first need is to recover my photographs, I have a saved disk on other place but 1.5 months are missed.
My second need is to rebuild Raid 1 without destruction of data.
Can I use Intel RST to repair the raid?
And if I do that, what will happened to my data on the part “unallocated”?

**Thanks**

Comment: Have you tried http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec ?